# Why is my sender.tag coming back as 0 in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have given a UIButton a tag of 1 inside the interface builder attributes section.

I then want to access the tag value of that button once it is pressed, so far I have done this but it is coming back as 0.

```
   @IBAction func attractiveMinus(sender: AnyObject) {

        println(sender.tag) //sender.tag comes back as zero.


    }
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of finding out the tag of a button can somebody please say where i'm going wrong?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the tag is set ? Are you added the tag to the correct button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, so I'd double check that you've updated the tag of the right button. Make sure that the updated IB files are being included in the build by wiping your derived data. Sometimes when you make a really small change like that, Xcode will use the previous version of the Storyboard/Xib that it has cached.

Also, since you know the sender is going to be a button, you can use `UIButton` in place of `AnyObject` to get the most out of Swift's type safety.

Comment: Thank you it is working now, I think as you said it wasn't compiling the storyboard fully.

Comment: Yep, this is a pet peeve of mine. Bugged me so much, I wrote an app to clean Derived Data often: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12&uo=4&at=11lMGu

Comment: Just having a look at your app, watchdog. Might buy it?